# how to get html content of <li> among the ajax <li> items

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-lists

using ajax i am returning set of list items all with different ids . i want to get the html content of one particular list item . i even have the id . but i couldnt get the html content with this

```
var li_element = $(req_id).html();
$('.selected_res_cls').append(li_element);
```

Answer (score 2):

Should use `#` to select on ID

```
var li_element = $("#" + req_id).html();
$('.selected_res_cls').append(li_element);
```

Comment: ya i am using it . i concatenated '#' to it already. its not working

Comment: Try to debug and see a) you have a real/correct ID and b) what is the HTML that comes back from the first line

Comment: when i alerted 'li_element' it comes as null

Comment: is this the proper way to get the content of the <li> which has been returned as ajax output

Answer (score 0):

Is your req_id variable prefixed with a hash, i.e. where `<li id="id1234">` you should be using $('#id1234')

Comment: ya i am using it . i concatenated '#' to it already. its not working

Comment: @rajprashanth r Might be way off here, but you have added the ajax output to the page first?  (As the jQuery will only look in the page's DOM)

Answer (score 0):

can't you just:

```
 $('.selected_res_cls').append($(req_id));
```

Comment: i used alert statements to check the ids. they are perfect. but couldn't grab the contents of it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> var li_element = $("#"+req_id).text();
>
> $('.selected_res_cls').append(li_element);